# Get only data that are repeated any the given year two or more times in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is the Raw Data.

```
Event   Year    Month
Event1  2011    January
Event1  2012    January
Event1  2013    February
Event1  2014    January
Event1  2015    March
Event2  2011    January
Event2  2014    April
Event3  2012    January
Event3  2015    March
Event4  2013    February
```

So only get those Event data that are occurred two or more times in given list of year i.e. [2011,2012,2013,2014].

So Output should be.

```
    Event   Year    Month
Event1  2011    January
Event1  2012    January
Event1  2013    February
Event1  2014    January
Event1  2015    March
Event2  2011    January
Event2  2014    April
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isin to filter years in the list. Groupby count and filter those greater than or equals to 2

```
s=df[df['Year'].astype(str).isin(lst)]
s[s.groupby('Event')['Month'].transform('count').ge(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter rows by list in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then are filtered duplicated events by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), last filter original column `Event`:

```
L = [2011,2012,2013,2014]
df1 = df.loc[df['Year'].isin(L)]

df = df[df['Event'].isin(df1.loc[df1.duplicated(['Event']),'Event'])]

print (df)
    Event  Year     Month
0  Event1  2011   January
1  Event1  2012   January
2  Event1  2013  February
3  Event1  2014   January
4  Event1  2015     March
5  Event2  2011   January
6  Event2  2014     April
```

Or you can test if greater or equal `2` is number of filtered `events`:

```
L = [2011,2012,2013,2014]
df1 = df.loc[df['Year'].isin(L)]

s = df1['Event'].value_counts()
df = df[df['Event'].isin(s.index[s.ge(2)])]

print (df)
    Event  Year     Month
0  Event1  2011   January
1  Event1  2012   January
2  Event1  2013  February
3  Event1  2014   January
4  Event1  2015     March
5  Event2  2011   January
6  Event2  2014     April
```

Comment: Hi, with dummy data your code is working fine. But I need logic which will consider at least two year from the given year list. While applying your logic to real time data that time at least one year is shown in output. I only need at least two year.

Comment: @Primecoder I think need change `df1 = df.loc[df['Year'].isin(L)]` to `df1 = df.loc[df['Year'].isin(L)].drop_duplicates(['Event',''Year])` for both solutions for test per nonduplicated events with years.